# Options accessible from NetBeans breakpointed variables pallette inaccessible from the editor

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans

I'm 98.6% Java noob.  I don't know if I'm saying this right, likely I'm not, but all of yesterday and up until about an hour ago, I've been able to do an IDE assisted *"dig in"* to objects/classes with the dot (.) and am clearly missing something on this cursed `ExamResults` object...

When I put the dot after the `ExamResults` object, I'm not getting access in the editor to [what I see in the variables pallette](http://goo.gl/8yTGe), after throwing a break point.   I'm [getting some default Java options](http://goo.gl/MtpOi), I wanna get me some of those objects/vars I see in the NetBeans variables pallette.

Can someone help me de-stupid or be less dumb?

Answer (score 0):

that is because your variables are private. You can't access them in the other classes even using the object of your ExamResults class.

you can get and set their values by getter and setter methods which will be public.